# Change QGIS Map Wraparound point

Tags: qgis

I have a shape file of country borders which I import to QGIS as a vector, and an .nc file of air temperature that I import as a raster. Both use the EPSG 4326 CRS. However, as seen in the picture, they have different centerpoints, with the American continents appearing on the left of center in the shapes file and on the right of center in the temperature raster file.

Is there a way to change the wrap-around point such that the maps align?

[image: screenshot of map layers]

Comment: I’d ask this over at the GIS-specific stack exchange site. As written, this really isn’t about programming.

Comment: Fair point, will give it a shot

Comment: See: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/468954/change-qgis-map-wraparound-point/468971#468971